# ELastic search exporter for prometheus throwing 403 errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, prometheus

I am running into following issue while running elastic search exporter(prometheus) for VPC based AWS elasticsearch instance.
Appreciate if anyone knows what could could be the issue?

**[elasticsearch-exporter-5558555bbf-blzhn elasticsearch-exporter] level=error ts=2020-09-02T15:56:20.134343455Z caller=clusterinfo.go:174 msg="failed to retrieve cluster info from ES" err="HTTP Request failed with code 403"**
[elasticsearch-exporter-5558555bbf-blzhn elasticsearch-exporter] level=debug ts=2020-09-02T15:56:20.13437932Z caller=clusterinfo.go:120 msg="updating cluster info metrics"

{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
{
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": {
"AWS": [
"arn:aws:iam::awsaccount:role/role1”,
"arn:aws:iam::awsaccount:role/role2"
]
},
"Action": [
"es:ESHttpHead",
"es:ListDomainNames",
"es:DescribeElasticsearchDomain",
"es:ESHttpPost",
"es:ESHttpGet",
"es:ESHttpPatch",
"es:DescribeElasticsearchDomains",
"es:ESHttpDelete",
"es:ESHttpPut"
],
"Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:awsaccount:domain/domain/*”
}
]
}

Comment: How are you doing authentication? IAM? Cognito?

Comment: We are using IAM,issue is due to access policy,but couldn't figureout what to tweak.